# my code throws error at ResourcerResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE

Tags: aem

My code throws error when trying to use `ResourcerResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE`, eclipse suggests some other keywords like `USER`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`, instead of `SUBSERVICE` and `getADministrativeResourceResolver` instead of `getService` `ResourceResolver`, I want to know if there is any dependency i should add to make it work

Comment: Can you share the relevant code and full exception trace?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the Maven Dependency which is used by ResourceResolver.Can you please check that which Maven dependency you are using.Mine is coming from Uber-jar and working fine.